# When activity is loaded, scrollview starts in middle and not top. Is there a way to fix it?

Tags: android

I have a very long scrollview. When the activity is loaded, the scrollview starts in the middle and not the top (and you have to scroll up to see the first items in the scroll view). Can't figure this one out, never had this happen before. Is there a way of fixing it? Here's my resource file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/activity_upgrade_now"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:padding="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".views.UpgradeNowActivity"
android:orientation="vertical">

<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:descendantFocusability="beforeDescendants"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">


        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="6dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="6dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="4dp">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:padding="5dp">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/auroracast_pro"
                    android:textAlignment="center"
                    android:textSize="14sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/get_pro"
                    android:textSize="10sp" />

                <ListView
                    android:id="@+id/lst_view"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:visibility="visible" />

                <Button
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/purchase_now_3_99_usd"
                    android:textSize="12sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:visibility="gone" />
            </LinearLayout>

        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                android:text="@string/scroll_to_see_pro_version_features"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:textAllCaps="true"
                android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
                android:textSize="10sp" />

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="25dp"
                android:tint="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
                ads:srcCompat="@drawable/downarrow" />
        </LinearLayout>


        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="6dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="6dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="4dp">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:padding="5dp">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/cloud_cover_and_light_pollution_maps"
                    android:textAlignment="center"
                    android:textSize="12sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/get_access"
                    android:textSize="10sp" />

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="60dp"
                    android:layout_height="60dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:layout_margin="5dp"
                    android:tint="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
                    ads:srcCompat="@drawable/map_icon" />

            </LinearLayout>

        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="6dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="6dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="4dp">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:padding="5dp">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/location_manager"
                    android:textAlignment="center"
                    android:textSize="12sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/location_manager_desc"
                    android:textSize="10sp" />

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="60dp"
                    android:layout_height="60dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:layout_margin="5dp"
                    android:tint="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
                    ads:srcCompat="@drawable/mappin" />

            </LinearLayout>


        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>


        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="6dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="6dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="4dp">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:padding="5dp">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/alerts_and_notifications"
                    android:textAlignment="center"
                    android:textSize="12sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/get_alerted"
                    android:textSize="10sp" />

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="60dp"
                    android:layout_height="60dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:layout_margin="5dp"
                    android:tint="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
                    ads:srcCompat="@drawable/alerts_icon" />

            </LinearLayout>


        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="6dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="6dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="4dp">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:padding="5dp">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/_27_day_kp_forecast_chart"
                    android:textAlignment="center"
                    android:textSize="12sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/_27_day_chart_desc"
                    android:textSize="10sp" />

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="60dp"
                    android:layout_height="60dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:layout_margin="5dp"
                    android:tint="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
                    ads:srcCompat="@drawable/chart" />

            </LinearLayout>


        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="6dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="6dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="4dp">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:padding="5dp">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/widgets"
                    android:textAlignment="center"
                    android:textSize="12sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/enable_three_widgets"
                    android:textSize="10sp" />

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="60dp"
                    android:layout_height="60dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:layout_margin="5dp"
                    android:tint="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
                    ads:srcCompat="@drawable/upgwidget" />

            </LinearLayout>

        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="6dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="6dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="4dp">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:padding="5dp">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/faster_update_frequency"
                    android:textAlignment="center"
                    android:textSize="12sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/in_the_pro_version_aurora_data_updates_more_frequently"
                    android:textSize="10sp" />

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="60dp"
                    android:layout_height="60dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:layout_margin="5dp"
                    android:tint="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
                    ads:srcCompat="@drawable/icon_time" />

            </LinearLayout>

        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="6dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="6dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="4dp">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:padding="5dp">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/priority_app_support"
                    android:textAlignment="center"
                    android:textSize="12sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/have_questions"
                    android:textSize="10sp" />

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="60dp"
                    android:layout_height="60dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:layout_margin="5dp"
                    android:tint="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
                    ads:srcCompat="@drawable/support_icon" />

            </LinearLayout>

        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="6dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="6dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="4dp">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:padding="5dp">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/and_more"
                    android:textAlignment="center"
                    android:textSize="12sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/more_features"
                    android:textSize="10sp" />

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="60dp"
                    android:layout_height="60dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:layout_margin="5dp"
                    android:tint="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
                    ads:srcCompat="@drawable/smile" />

            </LinearLayout>

        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/lst_view2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:visibility="visible" />

    </LinearLayout>


</ScrollView>

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/ads_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/ads_margin_top"
    android:gravity="bottom"
    android:visibility="gone">


</FrameLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

I tried adding

```
android:descendantFocusability="beforeDescendants"
android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
```

to the scroll view properties because I have read elsewhere on StackOverflow that this is how it's fixed, but it does not actually fix it.

Comment: I've had some more luck on adding `android:focusableInTouchMode="true"` to the first element inside scrollviews; so in your case maybe try adding it to the first `LinearLayout`. 

This fix doesn't always work; in some cases when some data loads later it still might started scrolled half-way the whole view for example. But worth a try.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try that and keep you updated. :)